# htaccess redirect based on http referer

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

One of my site is redirected to another site like this :

http://cccc-xyz.ch is redirected to http://abc.ch

Now want if the redirection is coming from http://cccc-xyz.ch, it should redirect to http://abc.ch/cccc-xyz-page by writing htaccess in http://abc.ch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://cccc-xyz.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://abc.ch/cccc-xyz-page/ [L,R]
```

Comment: thank you Zameer, this works but now http://abc.ch/,the home page is also redirecting to http://abc.ch/cccc-xyz-page/



# BEGIN WordPress
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://cccc-xyz.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://abc.ch/cccc-xyz-page/ [L,R]
</IfModule>`

# END WordPress